# magento 2 product class extending caused Type Error occurred when creating object: Company\Module\Model\Catalog\Product\Interceptor

Tags: magento2.3, interceptor

https://magenticians.com/override-model-magento-2/

I have followed the above tutorial to extend the Product class to show our custom compatible products with the product that the customer views. However after registering the module and completing all the steps, when I open the site, it shows the error "Type Error occurred when creating object: Company\Module\Model\Catalog\Product\Interceptor"

here is my extended Product.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\Module\Model\Catalog;

use Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductLinkRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media\EntryConverterPool;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\FilterProductCustomAttribute;
use Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;


class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{

    private $productCollectionFactory;


    protected $compatibilitySettingsArray = array(
        //some values
    );


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
        AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $metadataService,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url $url,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link $productLink,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\OptionFactory $itemOptionFactory,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterfaceFactory $stockItemFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory $catalogProductOptionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $catalogProductStatus,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config $catalogProductMediaConfig,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $catalogProductType,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $resource,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $resourceCollection,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\Processor $productFlatIndexerProcessor,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Price\Processor $productPriceIndexerProcessor,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Eav\Processor $productEavIndexerProcessor,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\CacheFactory $imageCacheFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\CollectionProvider $entityCollectionProvider,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\LinkTypeProvider $linkTypeProvider,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterfaceFactory $productLinkFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkExtensionFactory $productLinkExtensionFactory,
        EntryConverterPool $mediaGalleryEntryConverterPool,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface $joinProcessor,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $config = null,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\FilterProductCustomAttribute $filterCustomAttribute = null,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $_productCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $_productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $metadataService,
            $itemOptionFactory,
            $stockItemFactory,
            $catalogProductOptionFactory,
            $catalogProductVisibility,
            $catalogProductStatus,
            $catalogProductMediaConfig,
            $catalogProductType,
            $moduleManager,
            $catalogProduct,
            $collectionFactory,
            $url,
            $productLink,
            $filesystem,
            $indexerRegistry,
            $productFlatIndexerProcessor,
            $productPriceIndexerProcessor,
            $productEavIndexerProcessor,
            $categoryRepository,
            $imageCacheFactory,
            $entityCollectionProvider,
            $linkTypeProvider,
            $productLinkFactory,
            $productLinkExtensionFactory,
            $mediaGalleryEntryConverterPool,
            $dataObjectHelper,
            $joinProcessor
        );

    }

    function startsWith ($string, $startString)
    {
        $len = strlen($startString);
        return (substr($string, 0, $len) === $startString);
    }


    function getResolution($product){
        //some resolution based code for the product
    }

    function isCameraOrRecorder(){
       //code to get the type of the product
    }

    public function getCompatibleProducts()
    {
        //code to get the compatible products


    }


}
```

I have researched some google and stackoverflow resources but almost all of them come with duplicate ID problems. but mine is not. as I am also new to magento I am not sure exactly where to look for this kind of problem.

I have read this (https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-interceptor-pattern-code-generation/) article but this only talks about plugins, which is not my case.

I would appreciate any help I can get to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this The interceptor file needs to be re-create. So kindly run di:compile and clean cache
`php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php  bin/magento  cache:clean`

Comment: @MohitPatel I did that a few times during creation of the module and enabling it.

Comment: you re-create interceptor file . So you run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: I re-enabled the module after yesterday, and re-ran the commands but still it says : "Error filtering template: Type Error occurred when creating object: Company\Module\Model\Catalog\Product\Interceptor
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The original answer:** 
Move your inject `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $_productCollectionFactory`
Before `array $data = []`
And empty `generated` folder

**THE SOLUTION :**

As the original author noticed and suggested below in comments, I have made some mistakes with the `parent::construct` parameters. Fixed them, and the error is gone.

Comment: thank you for the answer, however as for the business times restriction I will be able to try it about 12 hours or so later. But I will definitely comment on whether it did work or not.

Comment: I did as you told, but still the same : "Error filtering template: Type Error occurred when creating object: Company\Module\Model\Catalog\Product\Interceptor"

Comment: Did you try ```php bin/magento setup:di:compile```?

Comment: yes, yesterday I have disabled the module, today I reenabled it, and ran all the commands setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile. cache:clean and cache:flush

Comment: Wrong in ```parent::__construct(```. Reference https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product.php#L399

Comment: ```$context```, ```$registry```, ```$extensionFactory``` ...

Comment: Sorry but could not get you. 

do you mean I need to add these lines after parent::__construct 

$this->eavConfig = $config ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\Config::class);
        $this->filterCustomAttribute = $filterCustomAttribute
            ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(FilterProductCustomAttribute::class);

Comment: No, missing some inject params in ```parent::__construct``` ```$context, $registry, $extensionFactory```...

Comment: thank you @bang.nguyen47 I edited the parent::construct and the error is gone now.

Comment: I don't know how many times I forget that once I extend a class I need to modify the parent call in the constructor to the class extended and not its parent (as is in the copied code) - it's nice these answers can jog your memory